# g++ selectively ignoring member declarations

Tags: c++, g++

g++ seems to be selectively ignoring member variables declared in class Player.  It also seems to believe that one of my member functions (void Player::update()) is declared as virtual.  The constants declared in the library I'm using (libtcod.hpp) aren't coming through either, despite working perfectly fine in all my other classes.  What's wrong here?

Here is the header file that goes along with Player.cpp:

```
#include "Map.h"
#include "Graphic.h"
#include "Dood.h"
#include "Villager.h"
#include "libtcod.hpp"

class Player: public Dood{
protected:
Graphic* rageGraphic;
TCODPath* myPath;
bool controlled;
void init(Graphic* _rage);
bool up, down, left, right;
static Player* myGuy;

public:
static Player* get();
Player(Graphic* _p);
Player(Graphic* _p, Graphic* _rage);
~Player();

void update();
void draw();
TCODPath* los(int x, int y);
};
```

And here are my error codes:

```
Player.cpp:4: error: 'Player* Player::myGuy' is not a static member of 'class Player'
Player.cpp: In member function 'virtual void Player::update()':
Player.cpp:8: error: 'TCODConsole' has not been declared
Player.cpp:8: error: 'TCODK_UP' was not declared in this scope
Player.cpp:12: error: 'TCODConsole' has not been declared
Player.cpp:12: error: 'TCODK_DOWN' was not declared in this scope
Player.cpp:16: error: 'TCODConsole' has not been declared
Player.cpp:16: error: 'TCODK_LEFT' was not declared in this scope
Player.cpp:20: error: 'TCODConsole' has not been declared
Player.cpp:20: error: 'TCODK_RIGHT' was not declared in this scope
Player.cpp:30: error: 'myPath' was not declared in this scope
Player.cpp:69: error: 'class Map' has no member named 'getRealMap'
Player.cpp: In member function 'void Player::init(Graphic*)':
Player.cpp:103: error: 'myPath' was not declared in this scope
Player.cpp:103: error: expected type-specifier before 'TCODPath'
Player.cpp:103: error: expected ';' before 'TCODPath'
Player.cpp: In destructor 'Player::~Player()':
Player.cpp:119: error: 'myPath' was not declared in this scope
Player.cpp: At global scope:
Player.cpp:124: error: no 'Player* Player::get()' member function declared in class 'Player'`
```

EDIT: Here's the beginning of Player.cpp, where most of the errors are.

```
#include "Player.h"
#include <stdio.h>

Player* Player::myGuy = NULL;

void Player::update()
{
if(TCODConsole::isKeyPressed(TCODK_UP)){
    up = true;
}

if(TCODConsole::isKeyPressed(TCODK_DOWN)){
    down = true;
}

if(TCODConsole::isKeyPressed(TCODK_LEFT)){
    left = true;
}

if(TCODConsole::isKeyPressed(TCODK_RIGHT)){
    right = true;
}


if(++counter == max)
{
    counter = 0;

    if(controlled){
        if(myPath->isEmpty())
        {
            posn* temp = Map::get()->getRandomDestination();
            myPath->compute(x, y, temp->x, temp->y);
            printf("Destination set to (%d, %d)\n", temp->x, temp->y);
        }else{
            myPath->walk(&x, &y, false);
            printf("Proceeding to (%d, %d)\n", x, y);
        }
    }else{
        int tempY = 0;
        int tempX = 0;

        if(up){
            tempY -= 1;
        }

        if(down){
            tempY += 1;
        }

        if(left){
            tempX -= 1;
        }

        if(right){
            tempX += 1;
        }

        up = false;
        down = false;
        left = false;
        right = false;

        printf("Projected movement is (%d, %d)\n", tempX, tempY);

        tempX += x;
        tempY += y;

        if(Map::get()->getRealMap()->isWalkable(tempX, tempY)){
            x = tempX;
            y = tempY;
            printf("walking\n");
        }
    }
}

VillagerManager::get()->collide(x, y);
}
```

Comment: If `update` is virtual in `Dood` then it will be virtual in `Player`. Also we need to see `Player.cpp` to help further.

Comment: your `update()` function *could* indeed be virtual if it is overriding a virtual function defined in the `Dood` base class (in that case, the `virtual` keyword can be omitted and the function would still be virtual). Anyway I suspect your problem is due to mutual (possibly indirect) inclusion between your header files. Please check if that is the case.

Comment: Since all the errors are in "player.cpp", we need to see that file too.

Comment: Player.cpp is pretty long; should I post the whole thing or a stripped down version?

Comment: @ReedLockwood: are you sure none of the headers `map.h`, `dood.h`, `villager.h`, `graphic.h` and `libtcod.h` directly or indirectly `#include` the header file you posted (I guess, `player.h`)?

Comment: I suspect that smth wrong w/ headers files you are #include... forgotten or extra `{`/`}`, missed `;`, or some typo like this...

Comment: Aaah, fellow roguelike developer.

Comment: Don't edit your question with an answer, post an answer to your own question.

Comment: You have a lot of error, so verify if your libraries is added correctly.

Comment: While I also guess that it's some typo causing these problems, I would suggest you distill a minimal(!) example from your code. Doing so, you will probably find the typo yourself.

Comment: @zaufi, another popular typo is opening a comment and closing it too late.